# Content Security Policy Meta Tag

Tags: html, .net, content-security-policy, nonce

I added my script on page like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var ByteArray = new byte[20];
                using (var Rnd = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
                {
                    Rnd.GetBytes(ByteArray);
                }

                var nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(ByteArray);

                context.Items.Add("ScriptNonce", nonce);
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", new[] { string.Format("script-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-{0}'", nonce) });

                await next();
            });

<script nonce='@nonceValue' src="https://sl.setrowid.com/index.js.php?mkodu=2700" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
```

but it set error in console:

> Refused to load the script 'https://push.setrowid.com/v3/push_loader.php?mkodu=2700' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-liYA5nqhRREBU3P1Wg/WrvVxmGQ='".

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' 'nonce-liYA5nqhRREBU3P1Wg/WrvVxmGQ='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Ryk1bebqkZRJKst9ISGjr+0FqT27dlA4N8+D6EPUtKo='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 1):

In the provided code you are allowing https://sl.setrowid.com/index.js.php?mkodu=2700 with a nonce but it is refusing to load https://push.setrowid.com/v3/push_loader.php?mkodu=2700. If content from setrowid.com can be trusted I would suggest to allow *.setrowid.com in script-src instead of using nonce, as it might not be applied in redirects or if script code calls another source.

The last error message is due to an inline script somewhere, but it is not provided in your question. The browser's console output will generally tell you where it is. It is not nonceable if it is a script inserting an inline script or if it is an event attribute. Event attributes (onclick, onfocus etc) need to be rewritten with event listeners.